# Nest Protect - Pathlight History

Tags: nest-api

My Nest Protect has the ability to automatically turn on the pathlight when it senses motion. This is a useful feature and somewhere it is actually being recorded when it turns on, because I can see the history in my Nest App for iOS.

I'm wondering if Nest has any plans to make those timestamps accessible via the API? Or is there already a way to find that information that is not part of the API? I'd like to export in a text format.

Thank you,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

The historical info isn't available but you can get the pathlight status over the api. You can even get the specific color.

Comment: Also I don't see pathlight status in the API. Can you confirm which object this is? https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference/ 

Also is making API calls directly to a nest protect reserved for wired versions?